# IF Statement with multiple/getting errors

Tags: sql, if-statement

I need to write a code the following

Give user parameter for selecting any carrier
Determine if the order is LTL
If LTL, determine if the selected carrier for the order matches the selected parameter of the rule
If true above, update delivery order table tracking number with probill number
If not LTL or Selected Carrier, do nothing.

here is the code I have

```
Declare  @CarrierName nvarchar(100) = '', @DeliveryOrder nvarchar(100) = ''


                        --DETERMINES IF AN ORDER IS LTL
 IF(ISNULL(
    (SELECT 'Yes' FROM DeliveryOrder
    INNER JOIN Carrier ON CarrierNumber = DeliveryOrderScheduledPickupCarrierNumber
    WHERE DeliveryOrderControlNumber= '@DeliveryOrder' 
    AND DeliveryOrderScheduledPickupCarrierClassOfServiceCode <> 'Ground with Freight Pricing'
    AND ( CarrierModeType = 'LTL' OR DeliveryOrderScheduledPickupCarrierClassOfServiceCode LIKE '%Freight%' ))
,'No') = 'Yes')
                        --CHECK IF CARRIER NAME = THE PARAMETER RULE
 BEGIN

If(@CarrierName = 'Yes' ,

        UPDATE dbo.DeliveryOrder 
        SET DeliveryOrderTrailerID = DeliveryOrderProBill 
        WHERE DeliveryOrderControlNumber = 'LTL', 'no')

--IF @CarrierName= 1 and @CarrierModeType = 'LTL'

END
```

Comment: Not enough info to assist ... please append to the question, the complete error message(s).

Comment: I Paul thanks for your response! My code works now. I had to troubleshoot with some old classmates lol

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE statements are different than SELECT statements. If you do not understand why one can be part of a condition and the other cannot, you need to go find out and come back afterwards.